# Can I pass in a NLTK tree instead of the original text to a LinearSVM in Python using SK-Learn, if not, what is the best way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, twitter, scikit-learn, data-science

I have been studying argumentation. I have written some software which interacts with the Twitter api, and enables me to build very weakly 'auto-annotated' datasets. The goal of the software is exactly that, easy creation of datasets for classification using distant supervision. It works great so far. I downloaded 1000 tweets which contained the phrase 'I argue that', assuming that the vast majority of these tweets will contain claims. I labelled them all as 'argumentative'. I then compiled another list of 1000 non-argumentative tweets. I know I can calculate the tree kernel for the constituency trees for argumentative sentences and use the kernel in a SVM, which is the best way to do it from the literature I've read, but that is outside my knowledge at this moment. So to keep it simply I have just been using a linear svm adapted from a sentiment analysis tutorial. I have generated the constituency trees using Spacy and library named Benepar, and have simply replaced the sentiment analysis data with my new data and labels, but the data being a set of trees rather than textual sentences. The classifier is set up as follows

```
unigram_bigram_clf = Pipeline([
  ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(analyzer="word",
                               ngram_range=(1, 2),
                               tokenizer=word_tokenize)),
                              # preprocessor=lambda text: text.replace("<br />", " "),)),
('classifier', LinearSVC(max_iter=1000000, verbose=True))
])
```

The max iterations was set to a million because it wasn't converging at 100000. I suspect 150000 would be enough as it usually converges around iteration 100k. I run the classifier and I'm getting roughly 80% accuracy predicting argumentative tweets which just seems high given it's set up for sentiment analysis using words. How would I know if it is overfitting, and is this even a reasonable way to classify? Given that the input is a list of trees, labelled as argumentative or not, what would be a good way to feed that data into an SKLearn classifier?